# Java Date getTime() method

Tags: java, date, gettime

I use `getTime()` method of Date class in java.

when I perform it in my local it return an value different with when I perform it in other pc whereas date value is same.

```
start.getTime()
```

Comment: milliseconds might be different

Comment: Time is stored in epoch against UTC.

Comment: *"whereas date value is same"* How are you viewing that? This question is extremely vague.

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` object is effectively just a container for milliseconds-since-the-Epoch values (milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970 at midnight UTC), which is the value you get from `getTime`. You've said "...whereas date value is same..." which suggests you're looking at other aspects of the `Date` object, like [`getHours`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours--) and such, but note all those "**Deprecated**" notices on those methods. They're there for a reason.

If you use something that's designed to handle timezones well (the new `java.time` stuff; at a pinch the old `java.util.Calendar`, but "well" is stretching it), you could easily have a `Date` object in one timezone which those mechanisms say is (for instance) 2017-02-01 at 11:06, and another in another timezone which they also say is 2017-02-01 at 11:06, but get different values from `getTime`. That's because of the difference in timezones.

Answer (score 0):

See javadoc for `Date.getTime()`:

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object

Note that the String representation of the Date instance (the String returned by `toString()`) may differ depending on locale and time zone settings, but the `getTime()` method will always behave as described above.